# Hash of records with values in start date to end date

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Event` model with `start_date` and `end_date` attributes. I am trying to create a hash with date as key and its value would be an array. The array will consists of events which occur on that date. An event is said to be occuring on that date if that date is on or in between the start date and end date of that event. Hope I am making sense. I have the code which gets me a hash with events grouped by `start_date`. It gives me a hash with date as key and value as array. That array has events whose start date is same as the key. Though this is in-complete solution. Can someone help me? I appreciate it.

**Code I have with incomplete solution :**

```
Event.all.group_by(&:start_date)
{Thu, 12 May 2016 05:59:34 UTC +00:00=>[#<Event id: 1, title: "Vacation", starts_at: "2016-05-12 05:59:34", ends_at: "2016-05-22 05:59:36", available: false, event_type: "vacation", practitioner_id: 1, maximum_prayers: 10, created_at: "2016-05-12 06:00:41", updated_at: "2016-05-12 06:00:41">], Fri, 13 May 2016 13:26:59 UTC +00:00=>[#<Event id: 2, title: "Meditation break", starts_at: "2016-05-13 13:26:59", ends_at: "2016-05-23 13:27:03", available: false, event_type: "vacation", practitioner_id: 1, maximum_prayers: 10, created_at: "2016-05-13 13:27:24", updated_at: "2016-05-13 13:27:24">]}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you need some events to be in that hash multiple times (the ones that span several days)?

Comment: Yes. That's what I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example that may be what you want. It loops through each event. For each event, it will loop through each date in the range and add it to an array for that date.

```
Event.all.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }) do |event, hash|
  (event.start_date.to_date..event.end_date.to_date).each do |dt|
    hash[dt].push event
  end
end
```